# Regex match differs between .net versions

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-standard

I am getting different regex matches when running below sample with `.netstandard2.0` and `.net6.0`

### Code

```cs
var stringToMatch = "sydney bogota berlin tokyo nairobi denver rio";
Console.WriteLine($"Input: {stringToMatch}");

var reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(\b(?!bogo|nai)\w*\b)\w+");

Console.WriteLine($"Output:");
foreach (var match in reg.Matches(stringToMatch))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

### csproj-netstandard2.0

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

### csproj-net6

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

### Output - netstandard2.0 & net472

Returning matches

```
Input: sydney bogota berlin tokyo nairobi denver rio
Output:
sydney
berlin
tokyo
denver
rio
```

### Output - net5.0 & net6.0

Not returning any matches

```
Input: sydney bogota berlin tokyo nairobi denver rio
Output:
```

https://regex101.com/r/Xn7X3w/1

Comment: I'm not sure about the reason for the discrepancy (and I haven't tested it yet) but what's the point of that capturing group? There can either be a match for what's inside the group or for the `\w+` at the end (and `\w+` wins because the group can be empty). Is something like `\b(?!bogo|nai)\w+\b` insufficient?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine i agree with you. But, the expression was taken out from a fairly large expression (which needs grouping). I wanted to know why it's behaving differently to understand it better.

Comment: I'll try to investigate this later when I have the time but it looks like the regex engine in .NET 6.0 fails to recognize a match after doing backtracking at `\w+`. FYI, a shorter pattern that will reproduce this is `\w*\b\w+`.

Comment: Strangely enough, `\b\S*\b\S+` works just fine. So, it might not be related to backtracing, but rather something to do with `\w`.

Comment: Setting the `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` works but matching in reverse order

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine, I think it is somehow actually a backtracking problem with `\w*` though since a lazy match using `\w*?` actually works and therefor characters, or in this case no characters but a starting position, is given back.

Comment: @JvdV Yes, what I meant to say is that it's not _just_ a backtracking problem (in the general sense); otherwise, we should see the same behavior with `\S`. It definitely has something to do with backtracking (specifically, after a word boundary anchor). I tested a few other alternatives and `[^\W]*` (which should be the same as `\w*`) works fine. `\ba*\ba` does _not_ match "a" but if you replace the first `a` with `[a-z]`, it works fine. This is very strange. Someone should probably file a bug report with Microsoft.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine it's not just `\w*`. Try `\d*\b\d+` with `123 456 789` and again with `\d*?\b\d+`. Very odd indeed. Ah, basically same finding as your previous comment =)

Comment: Fun fact - even `python` works in the same way as `.NET6` behaves. It's not returning any match - sample [here](https://replit.com/@dhilmathy/RegexTest#main.py)

Comment: @dhilmathy [Python works fine](https://ideone.com/50n0LF), you missed the raw string literal prefix.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine I'd created a bug and the fix is under review. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/74686

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turn out to be a bug in atomic loop inside and it was was acknowledged by Microsoft and there is a fix put in for this.

*Issue:* https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/74686 
*Fix:* https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/74726